# Unity 2D raycasting not going where expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player and an aim direction (represented as a normalized Vector2 where e.g. (1.0, 0) means pointing straight right). I want to cast a ray from the player in the aim direction until it hits part of my wall layer. I'm not sure why, but right now that raycast is not being aimed in the right direction at all, as drawn by Debug.DrawRay. Here's my relevant code:

```
 private void Update() {
     SetAimDirection();
     DoRaycast();
 }
 private void DoRaycast() {
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cast")) {
         RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, aimDirection, groundLayer);
         if (hit.collider != null) {
             Debug.Log(hit.collider.tag + " " + hit.point + " aim: " + aimDirection);
             Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, hit.point);
         }
     }
 }

private void SetAimDirection() {
    Vector2 aim = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    if (aim.magnitude == 0) {
        aim.x = facingRight ? 1 : -1;
    }

    aimDirection = aim.normalized;

    // Draw the reticle a constant radius from the player in aimDirection.
    Vector2 reticlePosition = new Vector2(body.position.x + (aimDirection.x * reticleRadius), body.position.y + (aimDirection.y * reticleRadius));
    crosshair.transform.position = new Vector3(reticlePosition.x, reticlePosition.y, 0);
  }
```

Here's a gif to illustrate the problem better (the white ray is meant to be passing through the red crosshair from the player's center, but isn't):

[image]

Comment: Without knowing how you calculate `aimDirection` is impossible to know what's happening.

Comment: @Gusman added that part of the code.

Comment: You are raycasting before computing the aim direction...

Comment: Oops, fixed that. It was a bad copy/paste from my code, I was doing the aiming first.

Comment: Is `body.position` the same as `transform.position`?

Comment: Yep, same result.

Comment: Strange, all seems ok, but maybe the problem is not the ray but the reticle. Assuming the reticle is where you want it to be, after setting `crosshair.transform.position` do this: `aimDirection = (reticlePosition - transform.position).normalized;` If with this the ray casts on the right direction then the problem is the reticle aim calculation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166505/discussion-between-ironwaffleman-and-gusman).

Comment: Just realised my mistake... `Debug.DrawRay` instead of `Debug.DrawLine`. Since I'm passing in two points to DrawRay instead of a point and a direction, it's drawing something completely different to what I expected. Fixing this fixed my issue.

Comment: You should add the response to this, explain a bit the difference about DrawRay and DrawLine as this info can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

So it was my own debugging function's fault; I was using `Debug.DrawRay` instead of `Debug.DrawLine`. The difference being, `DrawRay` takes an origin and a direction, whereas I was giving it an origin and destination, completely messing up the result. Using `DrawLine` fixed my issue.